# How can I validate a json pointer for a given Json Schema (even with $ref fields)?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema, jsonpointer

I am working with a JsonSchema that utilizes nested data structures where I use $ref for some properties and for others I just write in the data structures (no $ref). Basically I have to consider many types of JsonSchema Structures.

What I am trying to do is, given a list of Json Pointers, I want to validate that all the Json Pointer Expressions are valid properties existing in the Schema. The Json Pointer Expressions can be nested as well. Here is an example:

***product.schema.json***

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "https://example.com/product.schema.json",
  "title": "Product",
  "description": "A product from Acme's catalog",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": 
    "dimensions": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "length": {
          "type": "number"
        },
        "width": {
          "type": "number"
        },
        "height": {
          "type": "number"
        }
      }
    },
    {
    "warehouseLocation": {
      "description": "Coordinates of the warehouse where the product is located.",
      "$ref": "https://example.com/geographical-location.schema.json"
    }
  }
}
```

***geographical-location.schema.json***

```
{
  "$id": "https://example.com/geographical-location.schema.json",
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "title": "Longitude and Latitude",
  "description": "A geographical coordinate on a planet (most commonly Earth).",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "latitude": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "longitude": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  }
}
```

The above JsonSchema has the two types of nested schema structures. Lets say give these Schema, I also am give a list of JsonPtrExps:

```
["/dimensions/length", "/warehouseLocation/longitude", "/dimensions/mass"]
```

I am trying to find a way to use the schema to predict and validate which of the JsonPointerExpressions would return a valid property.
`"/dimensions/length", "/warehouseLocation/longitude"` would pass this validation but `"/dimensions/mass"` would not.

Also I would like to be able to make this decisions went I am only reading the ***product.schema.json*** even though I can access ***geographical-location.schema.json*** by using the $ref field.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you want to validate the JSON against the schemas yourself instead of using a JSON schema validation library that would do the job for you?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ It's a little more complicated but basically I need to allow users of the schema to attach a list of JsonPointerExpressions that will be used to carry out a function on JsonData that reflects the JsonSchema, but I need to prevalidate that the JsonPointerExpressions are valid properties defined by the JsonSchema, does that make sense?

Comment: Not entirely, but in that case wouldn't you simply want to parse the JSON schema as a simple JSON node and validate the paths as if they were standard JSON paths?

Comment: Yes but the obstacle is dealing with $ref cases.

Comment: JSON Schemas are (as you have shown) generally represented simply in JSON.  Evaluating a JSON Pointer against a JSON blob shouldn't be a great exercise.  There are probably libraries in Java that do this for you.  For example, [here's mine in .Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonPointer.Net) and [Microsoft's](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Json.Pointer).

Comment: Okay I kind of see. And how you want to handle the refs? I guess you want to load the referenced JSON schema and apply the paths there?

Comment: JSON Pointers, even during evaluation of a schema, can't see through `$ref`s.  They're just location identifiers in the raw JSON structure.

Comment: I am thinking of writing some logic to just manually check through $ref, I just need to find out how json validation does that

Comment: Are you expecting users to provide JSON Pointers which point through references as if the references had been in-lined? If so, this is not good. It's not always possible to in-line references, for example if they are recurisve.

Comment: Oh, you want to run the validate the JSON Pointers might be valid against the data validated by the JSON Schema? Interesting. Unless your schema is a lot more locked down (requires properties, prevents additional properties), you'll only be guessing. I've never seen anyone ask for such a tool, but you'd probably want to start by using a tool which creates an AST from the schema. You may find this to be a complex task.